# read webpage search results with Python

Tags: python, html, urllib

I want to be able to generate auto alerts for certain type of matches to a web search. The first step is to read the url in Python, so that I can then parse it using BeautifulSoup or other regex based methods.
For a page like the one in the example below though, the html doesn't capture the results that I'm visualizing when I open the page with a browser.
Is there a way to actually get the HTML with search results themselves?

```
import urllib

link = 'http://www.sas.com/jobs/USjobs/search.html'
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print myfile
```

Comment: You can not use urllib alone to see code that been rendered dynamically client side (JavaScript). The reason is that urllib only fetches the response from the server which is headers and the body (the actual code). Because of that I will not execute the client side code.

Comment: You will need to use Selenium - a browser automation module

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the data that is being generated dynamically using javascript by using traditional urllib, urllib2 or requests modules (or even mechanize for that matter). You'll have to simulate a browser environment by using selenium with chrome or Firefox or phantomjs to evaluate the javascript in the webpage.

Have a look at [Selenium Binding for python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)